# Unable to access header value in spring integration router int:mapping value

Tags: spring-integration

unable to access headers in the value attribute of router using like below

```
<int:router input-channel="route_profile"  expression="#jsonPath(payload, '$.entity')">
        <int:mapping value="headers.userId" channel="toWeb_send"/>
        <int:mapping value="headers.otherId" channel="find_preferences"/>
    </int:router>
```

Any thing here I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression is not what expected in that `value` attribute:

```
 <xsd:attribute name="value" type="xsd:string">
      <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation>
            A value of the evaluation token that will be mapped to a channel reference
            (e.g., mapping value='foo' channel='myChannel')
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
 </xsd:attribute>
```

This `value` is exactly what the mentioned top-level `expression` returns.

So, let's imaging your `expression="#jsonPath(payload, '$.entity')"` may return `foo` or `bar`, therefore the mapping must be like:

```
<int:mapping value="foo" channel="toWeb_send"/>
<int:mapping value="bar" channel="find_preferences"/>
```

If there is some logic around those headers, they have to be included in the expression evaluation. Or you may choose some other way to calculate the routing key.

Comment: I think in this scenarios I have to use  recipientlist router https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-implementations-recipientlistrouter